# Como faz para usar o comando UPDATE mais de uma vez?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, oledb

Nao consigo usar o comando UPDATE mais de uma vez.

Por exemplo, quando eu realizo o update no id 43, da certo. Porém quando vou tentar finalizar o 44, ele não finaliza, mas o 43 que pega o update..

Código:

```
    Int att,index;

    Private void DataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventsArgs e) {

       if(e.RowIndex &gt;= 0)
       {

         Index = e.RowIndex;                                               
         att = Convert.ToInt32(DataGrid.Rows[Index].Cells[0].Value);
       }
    }

 //quando clico numa célula, Att recebe o número que está //dentro dela, no caso correspondente ao ID na database tb. E index recebe o índice da linha.

    private void Btnfnz_Click(objetc sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         If(index >=0)
         {
              var linha = DataGrid1.Rows[index];
              cn.Connection = Conexão.conectar();
              cn.CommandText = "UPDATE Atendimento SET HorarioOut = ' " + Txthr.Text + " ' WHERE ID=@att";
              cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@att",att);
              cn.ExecuteNonQuery();
              cn.Connection = Conexão.desconectar();
         }
         else 
         {
               MessageBox.Show("Lista vazia!");
         }
         Refreshatt(); //Carrega o datagrid com dados do banco dados, onde horarioOut estiver em branco.
    }
```

Tudo funciona de Boa, porém quando tento fazer um novo update, ele até faz, porém no msm ID, fica fixado no primeiro ID que fiz o update.

**Imagens**

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xyqp6rA4Rk3AvneFaUlqk6AVvjQjbtSi/view?usp=drivesdk
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/190WFQ0cxGWYJw2aO66xBNvOsNftY7CAk/view?usp=drivesdk
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XS3NeZm7cU0_4Pi7r2fY4dCNNAjCKtf/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: você já fez essa pergunta antes o problema está na atribuição de valor da variável att...

Comment: E remova a sua pergunta anterior.

Comment: Testou a minha resposta?

Answer (score 1):

Esqueça o seu `DataGrid_CellClick` é um evento diferente do seu `Btnfnz_Click`. Se você debuggar o seu código verá que eles são executados em momentos diferentes e talvez o `DataGrid_CellClick` nem seja invocado quando você clica no botão...

Capture o índice da row através do seu próprio botão no evento do click.

```
private void Btnfnz_Click(objetc sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GridViewRow gridViewRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
     int index = gridViewRow.RowIndex;
     int att = Convert.ToInt32(DataGrid.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value);

     if(index >=0)
     {
          var linha = DataGrid1.Rows[index];
          cn.Connection = Conexão.conectar();
          cn.CommandText = "UPDATE Atendimento SET HorarioOut = ' " + Txthr.Text + " ' WHERE ID=@att";
          cn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@att",att);
          cn.ExecuteNonQuery();
          cn.Connection = Conexão.desconectar();
     }
     else 
     {
           MessageBox.Show("Lista vazia!");
     }
     Refreshatt(); //Carrega o datagrid com dados do banco dados, onde horarioOut estiver em branco.
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo, GridViewRow não aparece como um código válido aqui... O que eu preciso é de que o botão fnz pegue a linha que foi selecionada e faça o update nela. Como já disse, na primeira vez que tento tudo funciona, porém quando clico em outra linha, o update acontece na primeira linha, já testei o cellclick e ele retorna o ID correspondente a linha certinho, não acho que o problema esteja na variável att.

Comment: É uma aplicação web ou windows forms?

Comment: Se for windows forms o tipo correto é `DataGridViewRow`

Comment: Vou testar, vlww

Comment: Deu erro:  "Não é possível converter tipo "System.Windows.Forms.Control" em "System.Windows.Forms.DataGrodViewRow" "

Comment: Inclua o markup da sua grid na pergunta.

Comment: No lugar de qual nome?

Comment: Testei, mas continuou do mesmo jeito... Na primeira vez ele  faz o update na linha que eu selecionei, porém quando seleciono outra linha e faço o update. Ele realiza o update sempre na mesma linha... e nao na que eu selecionei.

Comment: tá faltando informações,  como eu disse na sua outra pergunta inclua o código do markup

Comment: Desculpa, o que é markup?